# Floating point precision with Math.Ceil (Java)

Tags: java, floating-point

I'm implementing a business rule to calculate a percentage increase on a stock level:

```
Stock level | Percentage Increase | Expected output
    100     |           93        |        193
```

As decimal stock levels are not well defined the rule is to round up the output:

```
public int calculateStockLevel(int rawStockLevel, double percentageIncrease) {
    return Math.ceil(rawStockLevel * (1 + (percentageIncrease / 100));
}
```

Actual output for the situation above: `194` (The test fails)

This looks like a floating point precision error, whats an elegant & readable way to get this test to pass?

Comment: Using floating points with money data is, uh, not a very good idea, precisely because of precision issues; you want to use `BigDecimal`; also, there is Joda Money (about the latter, I know it exists, I have never actually used it)

Comment: why  you are doing 1+ ??

Comment: @Prashant Its a percentage increase so for a percentage increase of 93% you effectively multiply by 193%

Comment: @Prashant That is the same as `rawStockLevel + rawStockLevel * (increase /100)`

Comment: @fge It's not money. It's units of something. All the problems of binary floating-point can be expected to crop up with decimal floating-point  as well.

Comment: if i am doing `Math.ceil(100 * (100+93.0) / 100) its giving 193.0`

Comment: basically because of 1 + (93.0 / 100) only the output is taking more precision that results to 1.9300000000000002 so ceil() is giving 194.0

Comment: @fge Its not money, stock products represents the number of adverts we offer a company on our website. BigDecimal solves the problem but isn't a particularly pretty solution. It'll do for now :)

Comment: `return Math.ceil(rawStockLevel * (100 + percentageIncrease) / 100);`

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc That works but why?

Comment: That's just a more recommended way, not always produce the correct result because binary floating-point types simply can't represent all decimal rational values.

Comment: No, LuuVinhPhuc's answer works (unless your numbers are truly huge) because you are working with integer values until the final division by 100.  So there is no roundoff before the division.  Division is correctly-rounded, which implies in particular that you won't land on the wrong side of an integer because of roundoff coming from the division.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use BigDecimal to specify what precision you want, but for your case you could do something simpler: just divide by 100 at the end.

```
public int calculateStockLevel(int rawStockLevel, double percentageIncrease) {
    return Math.ceil(rawStockLevel * (100 + percentageIncrease) / 100);
}
```

Comment: I've tried and tested this with integer percentages and it seems to work, but why is that any different to my solution in the question? It's mathematically identical....

Comment: @Ed0906 It would be mathematically identical if floating point arithmetic were real number arithmetic, or even rational arithmetic. It is a different arithmetic with its own rules that are designed to limit results to a finite set of binary fraction values by rounding. Since the floating point result may be slightly larger or slightly smaller than the rational number arithmetic result, operations such as ceiling and floor may get a different answer.

Comment: Because of the limitations of floating point. It cannot represent decimal numbers with 100% precision, even for seemingly simple cases like 1 + 0.93. (which will give 1.9300000000000002) However, it can represent integers with 100% precision. (unless they are too big, which is not the case here) And since in this second case we only have to deal with integers, the result will be exact.

Answer (score 0):

Binary floating-point types can't represent exactly every value in decimal. So `percentageIncrease / 100` will get the closest representation in binary. In your case the exact value of 0.93 in double precision is [0.930000000000000048849813083507](http://www.binaryconvert.com/result_double.html?decimal=048046057051), which is slightly more than the true decimal value. Therefore after `ceil` it'll be rounded up to 0.94

If you want exact decimal output you must use decimal arithmetic, like [`BigDecimal`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html). But in your case you can just do it in plain integer, utilizing the fact that the fractional part of the result must be larger than 0 if remainder of the division is non-zero.

```
int temp   = rawStockLevel * (100 + percentageIncrease);
int result = temp/100;
if (temp % 100 != 0)
    result++; // round up if not divisible by 100
return result;
```